# Typescript 5.3 and 5.4-beta treatment to `Readonly<[...number[], string]>`: What has changed?

Tags: typescript

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UBKECGATA9gOwDYgB4BtAOjOwFcBbAIwgCciBdAGigGdh6BLbAcyYA+ANxA)

```
type T = Readonly<[...number[], string]>;
```

In typescript 5.4-beta, `T` is `readonly [...number[], string]`.

In typescript 5.3, `T` is `readonly[...(string|number)[], string|number)`.

I don't see a change in the definition of `Readonly`. What has changed?

Comment: What changed is [ms/TS#57031](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/57031), as a fix to, among other things, [ms/TS#56888](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56888). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll post an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that addresses the question.

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance, probably after I wake up tomorrow (it's late in my time zone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inconsistency between `Readonly<[⋯]>` and `readonly [⋯]` when `[⋯]` is a [tuple type with a leading or middle rest element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types) type was considered a bug, as filed in [microsoft/TypeScript#56888](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56888).  This was fixed in [microsoft/TypeScript#57031](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/57031) and merged into the main branch at 2024-01-19T18:44:19Z, meaning that the old behavior is visible on 5.4.0-dev.20240119 and before:

```
type T = Readonly<[...number[], string]>;
//   ^? type T = readonly [...(string | number)[], string | number]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.0-dev.20240119#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UBKECGATA9gOwDYgB4BtAOjOwFcBbAIwgCciBdAGigGdh6BLbAcyYA+ANwBYAFAB6SVFkA9APwSgA)

and the new corrected behavior is visible on 5.4.0-dev.20240120 and after:

```
type T = Readonly<[...number[], string]>;
//   ^? type T = readonly [...number[], string]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.0-dev.20240120#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UBKECGATA9gOwDYgB4BtAOjOwFcBbAIwgCciBdAGigGdh6BLbAcyYA+ANwBYAFAB6SVFkA9APwSgA)